# Securty Of The Bootloader

Tags: grub2

I am interested in how installing the bootloader, GRUB, on another drive can increase security? I recently read something about an Evil Maid Attack on this post https://theintercept.com/2015/11/12/edward-snowden-explains-how-to-reclaim-your-privacy/ and Snowden suggests that installing your bootloader on a USB could help prevent against such an attack. Now, relating this to an Ubuntu install, if I were to put GRUB onto the USB instead of my hard drive upon an OS installation how would this prevent against someone else who has a USB with GRUB on it booting into my main OS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how it will work but I think the use of private/public keys will give you that uniqueness and therefore security layer. Somehow only your grub usb having the private key that will match the public one on the pc will keep others from booting the pc. I know you can put secure encrypted password to grub, so yeah something like that.